# Wordpress media upload limit?

Tags: plugins, memory

I've done numerous WP sites, written my own plugins, run my own server, etc etc.

But I have not seen this before. I just installed a fresh 4.7.1 and installed the [Proto theme](http://www.newsmartwave.net/?theme=porto_wp) and all its plugins.

When I went to add media files, I got:

```
Maximum upload file size: 2 KB.
```

I deactivated all plugins one by one...no dice. My PHP memory limit is set to 256MB for this installation via wp_config.php.

Googling the 2 KB limit turned up no results.

Anyone seen this before or know how to fix this limit?

Comment: Does this happen only when it's setup that way or for any and all WP installs? This is very likely to not be a WP issue but a general PHP/Server issue, the memory limit and the upload limits are separate and completely different things

Answer (score 4):

Three things you need to check.

`upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit` and `post_max_size` in the php.ini configuration file exactly.

All of these three settings limit the maximum size of data that can be submitted and handled by PHP.

Typically `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` need to be larger than `upload_max_filesize`.

---

This is the function in WordPress that defines the constant you saw:

```
File: wp-includes/media.php
2843: /**
2844:  * Determines the maximum upload size allowed in php.ini.
2845:  *
2846:  * @since 2.5.0
2847:  *
2848:  * @return int Allowed upload size.
2849:  */
2850: function wp_max_upload_size() {
2851:   $u_bytes = wp_convert_hr_to_bytes( ini_get( 'upload_max_filesize' ) );
2852:   $p_bytes = wp_convert_hr_to_bytes( ini_get( 'post_max_size' ) );
2853: 
2854:   /**
2855:    * Filters the maximum upload size allowed in php.ini.
2856:    *
2857:    * @since 2.5.0
2858:    *
2859:    * @param int $size    Max upload size limit in bytes.
2860:    * @param int $u_bytes Maximum upload filesize in bytes.
2861:    * @param int $p_bytes Maximum size of POST data in bytes.
2862:    */
2863:   return apply_filters( 'upload_size_limit', min( $u_bytes, $p_bytes ), $u_bytes, $p_bytes );
2864: }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to paste this code below in all .htaccess in root of folder :

```
Options -Indexes
php_value upload_max_filesize   1000M
php_value post_max_size         1000M
php_value max_execution_time    300
php_value max_input_vars        1600
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with new installs this week. You need to set the upload limits on your php.ini, **if you are on a shared server** you need to create a file called **.user.ini** then paste the code below

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin "Max Upload Size" that will let you easily increase the size of uploads. Fairly lightweight. See https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/