# How would I change the 10 MB limit to 5 GB in this script?

Tags: uploads, limit

Found this and it works, but want to change the 10 MB limit to 5 GB.

```
$upload_bytes_limit_reached = ( ( $filesize + $upload_bytes ) > ( 1024 * 1024 * 10 ) );
```

---

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', 'wpse47580_update_upload_stats' );
function wpse47580_update_upload_stats( $args ) {
    $size = filesize( $args['file'] );

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $upload_count = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'upload_count', true );
    $upload_bytes = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'upload_bytes', true );

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'upload_count', $upload_count + 1 );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'upload_bytes', $upload_bytes + $size );
}
```

## This function runs before the file is uploaded.

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpse47580_check_upload_limits' );
function wpse47580_check_upload_limits( $file ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $upload_count = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'upload_count', true );
    $upload_bytes = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'upload_bytes', true );

    $filesize = $file['size']; // bytes

    $upload_bytes_limit_reached = ( ( $filesize + $upload_bytes ) > ( 1024 * 1024 * 10 ) );

    $upload_count_limit_reached = ( $upload_count + 1 ) > 100;

    if ( $upload_count_limit_reached || $upload_bytes_limit_reached )
        $file['error'] = 'Upload limit has been reached for this account!';

    return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working. I removed the top half of the script. Don't know why it now works, but tested it and does what I wanted. Thanks for all your help and support. The original thread can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47580/22534), for those interested.

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpse47580_check_upload_limits' );
function wpse47580_check_upload_limits( $file ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $upload_bytes = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'upload_bytes', true );

    $filesize = $file['size']; // bytes

    $upload_bytes_limit_reached = ( ( $filesize + $upload_bytes ) > ( GB_IN_BYTES * 5 ) );

    if ( $upload_bytes_limit_reached )
        $file['error'] = 'Upload limit has been reached for this account!';

    return $file;
}
```

Comment: Nice, you figured it out. I came back late to this, because of the weekend. Just because you asked me in the comment, I didn't try the script, because your question was how to increase the limit, and as I said, if it's working with 10MB then it's also working with GB. Anyhow, you did it yourself, which is more rewarding anyway :)

Comment: @Nicolai It took some time, but got there. Thanks for your help tho, appreciate yours and others suggestions. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set [PHP upload limits](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252849/wordpress-media-upload-limit) properly.

Calculating 5 GB in Bytes would look like:

```
$5GBinBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5;
// or nicer
$5GBinBytes = pow( 1024, 3 ) * 5;
```

5GB is a lot of data, which might take some time. There is a good chance you have to crank up process time limits – `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` come to mind – and `memory_limit` as well.

As per comment by @swissspidy, WordPress defines the constant `GB_IN_BYTES`, usage:

```
$5GBinBytes = GB_IN_BYTES * 5;
```

Comment: processing won't be affected unless php's limit for single uploads is increased.

Comment: my understanding was that he just wants to increase the total (application controlled) limit and not PHP upload limits that affect single uploads

Comment: @inarilo Ah maybe you're right, let's wait what he says.

Comment: I tried that, but then when i test and upload of 29 MB, it shows the image missing in wordpress and no info. All php limits are high, as stated in your link.

For the 5 GB, I want it so its the maximum in total they can upload to their site, not max size in a single file upload.

Comment: @inarilo you're correct.

Comment: @Nicolai No it doesn't. the image file comes up blank in the wordpress media section.

Comment: FYI, WordPress defines the `GB_IN_BYTES` constant, so one can simply use `GB_IN_BYTES * 5` to describe 5 GB.

Comment: Tried the GB_IN_BYTES * 5;  still doesn't work. If anyone can/wants to  have a look and get it working for me, that would be lovely.

Just put <?php at the start, as i forgot to add it in the script i originally pasted.

Comment: @Nicolai I pasted the code above, into a file called quota.php and placed it into mu-plugins folder ( as thats where i want it ). did you do anything different ? I'm not using WP Multi-Site.